# Lighttpd mod_fastcgi respond only if conf file is using root url pattern

Tags: lighttpd

I have running lighttpd 1.4.59 on Lubuntu 21.10. My lighttpd.conf contains:

```
fastcgi.server = ( 
"/" => ((
                "bin-path" => "/var/www/html/script.fcgi",
                "socket" => "127.0.0.1:80",
                "min-procs" => 1,
                "max-procs" => 1,
                "doc-root" => "/"
            )))
```

There are still no problems and both 'localhost' and 'localhost/script.fcgi' are working. But if I change '"/" =>' to '"/foo" =>' then I can not get access to the /foo route because of '404 Not found' code. How to provide access to script.fcgi only if user type 'localhost/foo' in an address bar? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"check-local" => "disable"`

https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModFastCGI